# Add listview items to a programmatically made listview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a button that programmatically adds tabs with a listview attached to a tabcontrol.
I'm trying to access the listview i created so i can add a listview item(s) to it.

Here is my method that creates the tab with the list view

```
private void AddTabPage(string tabName)
    {            
        ListView lv = new ListView();
        lv.Name = String.Format("listView{0}", tabName);
        lv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        lv.GridLines = true;
        lv.View = View.Details;
        lv.Columns.Add("Property", -2);
        lv.Columns.Add("Value", -2);                

        TabPage tPage = new TabPage(tabName);
        tPage.Name = String.Format("tab{0}", tabName);
        tPage.Controls.Add(lv);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tPage);

        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tPage;
    }
```

As you can see i have made the control names dynamic. Example (listviewComputer1, tabComputer1) Now how would i go about accessing the listview after it has been created?

Note: I can't add the listview item(s) at the time of creating the listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get TabPage by name, then get ListView control from its controls:

```
var lv = tabControl1.TabPages[tabName].Controls
                    .OfType<ListView>()
                    .First();
```

Now you can add items to ListView:

```
lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new []{ "Foo", "42" }));
```

Comment: That was an incredibly fast and accurate reply! Thank you so much! I doubt I would have ever got that one on my own.